# Mocking a static method in abstract class

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I have a class A which calls a static method of an abstract class B which throws some exception. I wanted to test for this exception. I am using junit 4.1, mockito 1.9.5 and powermock 1.6.6. The classes are :

```
 abstract class B {
 public static void meth(String str) throws SomeException1, SomeException2,SomeException3 {
 //some code 
  }
}

class A{
 public void method() throws SomeException1, SomeException2,SomeException3 {
  B.meth1("abc");
  }
}
```

I want to test these exceptions and here is my test class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(B.class)
class Test throws Throwable {

public void testException(){
PowerMockito.mockStatic(B.class); //Line 6
when(B.meth(Mockito.any(String.class))).thenThrow(new SomeException1(), new SomeException2(), new SomeException3() );
A obj=new A();
obj.method();
   }
  }
}
```

While executing this test case I get an exception

```
org.powermock.api.mockito.ClassNotPreparedException: 
The class B not prepared for test.
To prepare this class, add class to the '@PrepareForTest' annotation.
In case if you don't use this annotation, add the annotation on class or  method level. 

at org.powermock.api.mockito.expectation.reporter.MockitoPowerMockReporter.classNotPrepared(MockitoPowerMockReporter.java:32)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockTypeValidatorFactory$DefaultMockTypeValidator.validate(MockTypeValidatorFactory.java:38)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.AbstractMockCreator.validateType(AbstractMockCreator.java:10)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.createMock(DefaultMockCreator.java:56)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.mock(DefaultMockCreator.java:46)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic(PowerMockito.java:71)
at Test.testException(Test.java:6)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Any suggestion as to why am I getting this ?

Comment: Just for the record: I hope you understand that you are spending **hours** to enable you testing a design ... that is simply written to be hard to test? If you have the possibility to do so: rather spent that time to turn your hard-to-test into an easy-to-test design. And get rid of the need to mock static calls, and throw out PowerMock(ito). Would make your whole life a whole lot simpler.

Answer (score 2):

You need this: `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`

Comment: When I add this, eclipse automatically imports org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner and on executing it gives java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type PowerMockRunner not present , Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundExceptionPowerMockRunner
 at sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.generateException(TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.java:46)

Comment: This seems to be a separate issue, unrelated to the basic problem that this question is about.  I have never seen this before, so I don't know what causes it.  Hopefully someone else will show up who knows how to fix this.  If I were to take a wild guess, I would say that powermock is available for compilation but it is not in your classpath at runtime, and it may have something to do with the fact that the testing configuration is (has to be) slightly different from the production configuration.

Comment: So, you need to see how other libraries (like junit) are included in your classpath, and make sure that powermock is included the same way.

Comment: There was some discrepancies in the code and resetting it to the head of my git branch resolved this exception. But now the a my test case passes but does not throw the exception also if say when(B.meth(Mockito.any(String.class))).thenThrow(new SomeException1(), new SomeException2(), FileNotFoundException ); ,  it pasess the test case but down not throw any of the exception? Any idea ?

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question. Accept one of the answers here; and move on. Avoid playing "i have one more thing" via comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use powermock to mock static method.

Code example

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class TestStaticMethodExample {
    private SomeClass c = new SomeClass ("g", "123");

    @PrepareForTest({ SomeStatic.class })
    @Test
    public void stubStaticMethod() {

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(SomeStatic.class);

        PowerMockito.when(SomeStatic.getSummary()).thenReturn(new 
    SomeClass("t", 9999));

    }

}
```